# Google Maps API e Google Indoor Maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, cakephp-2

Boa tarde. Trabalho com Projeto de redes e cabeamento estruturado e desenvolvi uma aplicação para o mapeamento de fibra óptica com o Google Maps API, no qual pode-se ver na seguinte URL:

http://mapeamentonti.ufms.br/

Nos brainstorms com a equipe, todos acharam interessante a adição das plantas da empresa para adição do cabeamento estruturado nos prédios, assim teríamos as estruturas de cada prédio da Universidade. Em busca de soluções, descobrimos isso:

http://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/

A dúvida não seria nem de programação em específico e sim se é possível aplicar o Indoor Maps diretamente no nosso Mapeamento, sem que precise enviar as plantas baixas para o Google (o que pode ser barrado pela burocracia do setor público).

Se é possível, onde posso encontrar alguma documentação a respeito? Entrei nos fóruns de discussão do Google para fazer essa pergunta e os mesmos me mandaram para o Stack Overflow em inglês.

Obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia, o sistema de mapeamento de redes opticas http://mapeamentonti.ufms.br/ você pode disponibilizar para estudos, achei muito interessante e gostaria de implementar aqui na empresa. Obrigado!

Comment: Opa Jean, claro! Como posso contactá-lo?

Answer (score 3):

O Indoor Maps ainda não está disponível para a API v3 do Google Maps mas existe uma solução que poderá satisfazer as vossas necessidades.
A classe GroundOverlay, Sobreposições de Solo no nosso português, permite colocar uma imagem numa determinada localização, aumentando ou diminuindo de tamanho consoante o nível do zoom.
A documentação pode ser encontrada aqui: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#GroundOverlays

Mas basicamente só necessitas de definir os pontos NE e SW da planta baixa:

```
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.716216,-74.213393),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.765641,-74.139235));
```

depois defines a path da imagem e as coordenadas NE e SW anteriormente definidas e colocas a sobreposição no mapa:

```
   var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("http://pathdaimagem.jpg", imageBounds);
   oldmap.setMap(map);
```

Para completar podes criar controlos de mapa personalizados que mostram ou escondem as plantas baixas.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo blz??

Seguinte esse site http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/custom_streetview/ explica certinho como você faz para criar um Indoor Map

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Posso não ter percebido, mas neste link parece explicar como customizar *Street View* e não *Indoor Map*.

Comment: O step 3 mostra o código, os steps anteriores falam de como montar as fotos.  http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/custom_streetview/3.html

Comment: Bom dia pessoal. Parece que, ao meu ver, ele tem razão Mateus, essas informações são a respeito do Street View (o que são bastante úteis para empreendimentos futuros). Mas não falam exatamente do inddor maps.

Comment: Paulo bom dia, realmente eu me confundi estava pensando em um Street View, em relação ao Indoor Maps eu encontrei as seguintes referencias http://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/, https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1711534?ref_topic=3100918&p=gmm_guidelines&rd=1, https://maps.google.com/floorplans/find?hl=pt-BR